# driver1.openNotifications(); method not working on my android automation test script

Tags: java, android, appium

Here's the I'm trying automate using appium but got stuck.

- I'm launching the application and triggering and content upload (Working)
- Once upload is upload is complete, I want to read the application notification which displays 'Upload Complete' (No working)

Issue: Notification is not opening.

It would be helpful someone can provide a sample code to run above test scenario.

Appium Version used: 1.4.13
API Level 19

```
    driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    driver1.findElement(By.id("jio.cloud.drive:id/backup_all_now")).click();
    driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(@resource-id,'backup_checking_text') and @text='Backing up…']"));
    driver1.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
    driver1.openNotifications();
    List<WebElement> allnotifications=driver1.findElements(By.id("android:id/title"));

    for (WebElement webElement : allnotifications) {
        System.out.println(webElement.getText());
        if(webElement.getText().contains("Upload Complete")){
            System.out.println("success");
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you paste your code snippet here?

Comment: Updated code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems to be correct. I suggest you to try the same scenario on different device.

openNotifications() method internally calls swipe method. if openNotifications() does not work then you can use swipe method as below :

```
driver.swipe(500, 0, 500, 800, 2000);
```

This should work. If it does not work, then please Enable "Pointer location" in Developer options of Android device. And observe the exact action that is happening on the device you will see the pointers.